# Impossible custom layout in gwt?

Tags: gwt, layout

I want to create a custom panel/layout and it's seeming pretty impossible at this point. I need the components to start in the upper left corner and stack downward until they fill the panel vertically, then wrap to the top of the next column and so on until they eventually fill the screen and create a horizontal scrollbar. After an entire day of trying I've decided it's only possible by abusing GWT (and I assume the whole web browser) adding crippling complexity and terrible performance. Please let me know if I'm missing something and layout like this is possible. Thank you!

Lame solution: Have a small (almost invisible) AbsolutePanel where every string is displayed within a div and measured (getClientWidth/height()). Then each panel can calculate it's size based on the strinsg, borders, padding, etc. it contains. Once each panel knows it's size, they can be layed out relative to the sizes of the other panels in the contianer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out FlexTable, which allows you to specify the row,column for the widget to be added